# Summarizing data from multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a google sheet like this example to track scores for disc golf:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uxDFXg2kivZWKICeVklugyXH1OWqsq_s5qXZYzgHkt8/edit?usp=sharing

It works great for tracking day to day scores but it would be really awesome to have a single sheet at the beginning that could say everyones total scores that they have gotten. Also note that the names may not be the same in each sheet.

So in this example I would want to have a new sheet that would automatically calculate the scores from the other sheets and show:

```
Mike 67,71,65
George 83,70
Phillip 79,72,65
John 66,71
Henry 69
```

I am very unfamiliar with excel formulas and have been struggling to get this started. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not excel formulas but Google sheets ones. They are not all the same. In this case (without opening your project) you might need TEXTJOIN.

Comment: question 1: are all the names already known ?
question 2: are all the sheets already available, I mean you have three sheets now, but can another sheet be added later, and that sheet should be considered too in the calculation of total score?

Comment: All names are not yet known because new sheets can be added and they might have new people. And the new sheets should also be added to the summary page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Google Apps Script to accomplish what you are looking for. The idea of the code is that it will iterate over every Sheet in your Spreadsheet, gather all the players and all their values, and finally create a summary and put it into the "Summary" sheet (that sheet must exist in your Spreadsheet, with strictly the same name):

```js
function updateSummary() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var summarySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary');

  var allScores = {};

  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getName() == 'Summary') continue;

    var nColumns = sheets[i].getLastColumn();

    var names = sheets[i].getRange(1, 1, 1, nColumns).getValues()[0];
    var scores = sheets[i].getRange(20, 1, 1, nColumns).getValues()[0];

    for (var j=0; j<nColumns; j++) {
      var currentName = names[j];
      var currentScore = scores[j];

      if (!allScores.hasOwnProperty(currentName))
        allScores[currentName] = [];

      allScores[currentName].push(currentScore);
    }
  }

  summarySheet.clear();

  for (var key in allScores) {
    var row = [key].concat(allScores[key]);
    summarySheet.appendRow(row);
  }
}
```

This will create, with the data given, the following data in the "Summary" Sheet:

[image]

Instead, if you prefer to have two columns as you described in your question (with the second one holding every score separated by commas), you would simply need to replace the last for-loop in the code above for the following one:

```js
for (var key in allScores) {
  var row = [key].concat(allScores[key].join(','));
  summarySheet.appendRow(row);
}
```

Finally, you can create an image in the "Summary" sheet which can serve as a button to run the script. To do so:

1. Within your Sheet, click on Insert>Image>Image **over** cells.
2. Select any image of your choice.
3. Select the newly created image and click on the three dots icon that appears on the top-right corner of the image.
4. Click on "Assign script" and put the function name (in this case, `updateSummary`) and click on OK.

Comment: this is great, instead of grabbing the 20th row with the results, is there a method to grab all the data, just a simple concenation across common columns in multiple sheets?

Comment: Hey @Datanovice, thanks for your comment. I am unsure as to what you mean by this question. Could you please develop a bit more? Cheers!

Comment: for e.g [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uKm2Bl7GIQIumtV5Z7kvZswuq7KGh82jgOB9aHU3X4M/edit?usp=sharing) I'd wonder how you would loop through all the possible ranges and grab all the data under the columns and concat it into a single sheet, very similar to this solution but change `var scores = sheets[i].getRange(20, 1, 1, nColumns).getValues()[0];` to grab all values instead of row 20

Comment: This looks great! I will check it out

Comment: This is awesome! Didn't even know this kind of functionality was possible and is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 'MikeGeorgePhillipJohn 121519'!A1:D20, 
 'MikeGeorgePhillipJohn 122019'!A1:D20, 
 'MikeJosephPhillipHenry 122719'!A1:D20}), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col20)
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1
  label sum(Col20)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 'MikeGeorgePhillipJohn 121519'!A1:D20, 
 'MikeGeorgePhillipJohn 122019'!A1:D20, 
 'MikeJosephPhillipHenry 122719'!A1:D20}), 
 "select max(Col20)
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col20
  pivot Col1", 0),,999^99)), " "))
```

[image: 0]